# How to substring an NSString in iOS

Tags: ios

I have an

```
NSString *str=@"123456789123456789123456";
```

My new string should be

```
NSString *newStr =@"1234 5678 9123 4567 8912 3456";
```

Can any one help me 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by substring?

Comment: Check the NSString class reference, you have some substring utilities there... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: I want to add Space after every 4 character

Comment: Does the string always contain digits?

Comment: no is can be AlphaNemeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this..

```
NSMutableArray *subStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
NSRange range = {0,subStrLength};
for(int i=0;i< [str length]; i+= subStrLength)
{
    range.location = i;
    [subStrings addObject:[str substringWithRange:range];
}
```

**Update:** `NSString *strWithSpace = [subStrings componentsJoinedByString:@" "];`

Comment: I want to add Space after every 4 character to above string

Comment: @user2223368 that's you want to new string with spaces.

Comment: Yes MY New string should be like this 1234 5678 9123 4567 8912 3456

Comment: @user2223368 See my updated answer. It will help you.

Comment: ThankQ it was help full to me

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str=@"123456789123456789123456";
NSMutableString *mutableStr = [str mutableCopy];

for (int i = 4; i < mutableStr.length; i += 5) {
  [mutableStr insertString:@" " atIndex:i];

}
```